# Hiding and showing a program started by Systems.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, process

The following code is how I initiate the program:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process fooProgram;
fooProgram = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("foo.exe");
```

Now I know that you can set the StartInfo parameters to have the program run hidden but is there some way to hide it and bring it back during processing as I only want to show certain screens to the user and then I want it to automatically hide itself when the information has been shown. I was hoping for something as simple as fooProgram.Show() and fooProgram.Hide() but it appears that it is not quite that simple.

Simply sending it behind the other program and bringing it back to focus would be enough as well, however this also doesn't seem to be in the list of available actions.

The program being launched is a .NET 4 form.

Comment: I think you'll have to use the Win32 API to do this.  I'm not aware of any .NET functionality that would allow that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in .NET - you'll need to use interop.

Check out these functions:

- [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So you'll use `FindWindow()` to get the window handle and then you'll execute those other functions on that handle. In terms of exposing those functions to C# check out this awesome interop website: [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/)

Also, instead of `HWND` use `IntPtr`.